# Javascript - How to evaluate this string to TRUE

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I would like to compare `string1` value to `string2`

**string1:**

```
<ul>
<li>&nbsp;</li>
</ul>
```

**string2**

```
<ul><li>&nbsp;</li></ul>
```

I got this string result from ckeditor so that i can fire validation, See in action [here](https://jsfiddle.net/e8aut2jL/1/)

Comment: Please review [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, i wanted to provide code snippet but it gives me javascript multi line error when i copy the string, so i gave a jsfiddle link

Comment: Use an XML parser to compare them or just strip the new lines.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the `\n` (new line) character

```js
var str1 = `<ul>
<li>&nbsp;</li>
</ul>`;

var str2 = `<ul><li>&nbsp;</li></ul>`;

if(str1.replace(/\n/g, "") === str2){
  console.log("It is a match!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove line returns and then compare.